# same string comparison not working mysql

Tags: php, mysql, collation, string-comparison

I created a script in PHP that basically uploads a CSV (generated externally) with first names to a MySQL database and then process each row to determine if a first name is from a male or female using an external API.

Once it has evaluated each row (name), it stores the names on secondary tables (existing_names or missing depending on the result).

To avoid wasting my API requests and make my process faster, every time a CSV is uploaded I run the following query to determine if a name already exists in the tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT nl.name 
FROM namelist nl 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT name 
    FROM missing 
    UNION 
    SELECT name 
    FROM existing_names 
    ) en ON en.name = nl.name 
WHERE en.name IS NULL
```

From this query I get the set of new rows that will be evaluated with the help of the API.

My DB and all my tables have this value as Collation: utf8_unicode_ci but I'm getting weird results as names like "A LUIGI" have different lengths in both tables: '8' in namelist and '7' in existing.

As a result, the query above is returning a big number of names that have already been evaluated.

Two questions:
1.How should I structure the query to standardize collation in this case?
2.What code should I add to my PHP script to avoid populating the DB with strings with a different collation?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but, out of interest, how will you handle unisex names like "Charlie", "Jamie", "Jesse", "River" etc? How about names which are male in one language but female in another (eg "Jean")? And although I don't know what your system does, will it need to and be able to deal with transgender users delicately?

Comment: @MattRaines Im using it for Latin American names, at least in Spanish there are just a few names that can be unisex and most of the times are composed by two names where the first defines the gender. (ex. "Jose Maria", "Jose Guadalupe") At least for this project, the gender will be just for analytics purposes, we won't use it to send any communication to the users.

Answer (score 3):

Garbage in, garbage out.  You probably have an extra space in "A LUIGI" in one of the tables.  To debug it, please do

```
SELECT name, LENGTH(name), CHAR_LENGTH(name), HEX(name)
    FROM ...
    WHERE name LIKE '%LUIGI%';
```

for each table.

- For the 7-char version, I would expect both lengths to be 7 and the HEX to be `41204C55494749`.
- If there is an extra `20` at the beginning or end, then you should have used `TRIM` as you inserted the text.
- If there is an extra `20` in the middle, that is another GIGO case.
- If `CHAR_LENGTH` is 7 but `LENGTH` is 8, then we need to look at the HEX to see if some utf8 character is mascaraing as an English/Italian letter.

Once you have the HEX for the two strings, we can discuss 'collation' issues.